# Subtracting a fitted polynomial from a dataset in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have one curve, a scatterplot, which is the plot of the data set I am working with (named 'mydata') and the other curve which is the fitted 2nd degree polynomial curve that I obtained from the data set. 
The scatterplot was obtained with a simple plot function:

```
plot(mydata)
```

The code I used for the fitting is:

```
fit<-lm(mydata$Volts ~ poly(mydata$Frequency, 2, raw=TRUE),data=mydata)
#summary(fit)
lines(mydata$Frequency, predict(fit))
```

Now, I would like to subtract the fitted polynomial from the dataset. Following was my approach:

```
given<-plot(mydata)
fit<-lm(mydata$Volts ~ poly(mydata$Frequency, 2, raw=TRUE),data=mydata)
new<-lines(mydata$Frequency, predict(fit))
corrected<-given-new
plot(corrected)
```

The error I received was:

```
Error in plot(corrected) : object 'corrected' not found
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: That error  typically means that you do not have an object named `corrected`. If you provided some example data that ensures a reproducible error it would help people greatly to help you. You can use the output of the `dput(mydata)` command to share your data here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to subtract graphical elements. You should perform any math/operations on your data before trying to plot it. Something like the following may work. However without sample data this is just an educated guess.

```
given <- mydata$Volts
fit <- lm(mydata$Volts ~ poly(mydata$Frequency, 2, raw=TRUE),data=mydata)
new <- predict(fit)
corrected <- given-new
plot(mydata$Frequency, corrected)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran a reprex (although technically, I need a random seed for a true reprex, but because of the actual issue with the code, that doesn't matter here) on nonsense data.

```
volts=rnorm(50,mean=220,sd=5)
frequency=runif(50,min=30,max=90)

mydata=data.frame(Volts=volts,Frequency=frequency)
given<-plot(mydata)
fit<-lm(mydata$Volts ~ poly(mydata$Frequency, 2, raw=TRUE),data=mydata)
new<-lines(mydata$Frequency, predict(fit))
corrected<-given-new
plot(corrected)
```

The scope of my answer is strictly to explain why the **not found** error showed up.  Daniel's code shows you the fix.

I'm not sure why the response of [Daniel O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10442423/daniel-o) was not chosen, because it worked. I know it is frustrating when you clearly *defined* something and your source code is right in front of you, yet the interpreter says `NOT FOUND`.  The lesson learned here when you get this situation, to check for NULL.  It's a good habit in general for R.